# Is there a List View for Google Photos?

Tags: google-photos

Looking at one of my Google accounts,  I got an email saying Google account storage full.

Google drive showed as 99%-100%

I figure it's related to the fact that I recall on one of my phones, it askedd me if I want to back up photos, and asked me about whether I wanted to compress them, and I said yes to back them up and no to compressing them('cos I was wary of it messing with the photos as they were on the phone),  and I gave that email account.

I downloaded all that was on Google Drive and deleted it all, and it said something like Google Drive is 80% full. Even though there were no longer any files showing on Google Drive.

I then downloaded Google Drive Desktop  from https://support.google.com/drive/answer/7329379#zippy=%2Cdownload-install-google-drive-for-desktop
to see if that made it more clear and it said my storage was full and gave this link

https://one.google.com/u/2/storage?utm_source=drive&utm_medium=desktop&utm_campaign=error_dialog_warning&pli=1

[image]

So I see the culprit is google photos as I suspected. And it gave a link to it here

https://photos.google.com/?pli=1

Many videos and photos going back a few years.

But I see no List View

[image]

If there was a List View then there'd be a chance for me to try to highlight them all so as to download them.

I suppose I could try https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190  so,  https://takeout.google.com/  the exporting feature. And  deselect all and then only select Photos and click expo rt.

I'm wondering if there was a list view for Google Photos which might make it easy to select all?